# Flex: Does anyone know a good HTML editor?

Tags: html, apache-flex, adobe, rich-text-editor

I am looking for a flex component that could allow me to edit rich text with images.

Something like the RichTextEditor from flex except it allows you to add and preview images too, and which can generate the HTML code too.

Comment: In case you wanted it for Adobe AIR http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/AIR  ... It may work with Flex as well... I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks Chris! that's exactly what I was looking for. Any idea what files i need to include to my AIR app and how can I make communication with it ? I cannot find any documentation on this.  Thanks again!

Comment: The link to FCKeditor is outdated. The release 2 AIR integration download isn't any longer available. Aditionally, release 3 of FCKeditor doesn't come along with an AIR adaptor.

Comment: "The compatible version is currently available as of FCKeditor 2.6 Beta"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text Layout Framework is the ANSWER :)

more details here:
http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/tlf/Text+Layout+Framework

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Flex HTML Editor is coming from here:
http://www.oscar-mejia.com/blog/post/i-need-a-flex-html-editor

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a flash application created with flex,
I need a flex control like that one that i can use inside my flex application. :)